# Is の後で textbook-ish Japanese?

Tags: grammar, particle-で, formality

In the textbook "Japanese For Busy People I" (which uses only kana, not kanji), on page 161, there is the following sentence.

> ごぜん １０じから ごご ３じまでです。かいぎの あとで さっぽろししゃに いって、さとうさんに あいます。

Using kanji, I think it would look like this:

> 午前１０時から午後３時までです。会議の後で札幌支社に行って、佐藤さんに会います。

However, a native Japanese speaker is suggesting I drop the "で" after the "の後" from the following sentence (I think to make it more natural):

> チェックインの後で、衣料品店に行きました。

Is having a "で" rather formal and textbook-ish Japanese?

Comment: It is 札幌支社 (= Sapporo branch), not　札幌市会社 (which makes no sense).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not particularly bookish or formal to say ～～の後で or ～～した後で, but it is true that the で gets omitted quite often in conversations.

If one uses a で, one could emphasize the 後 part, stressing the fact that the action should be performed AFTER something, not before.